# Require working code of RepeatBox and its row click event to jump on the respective page in smartface.io

Tags: javascript, android, smartface.io

Please share the working code for repeatbox in smartface.

I have been testing all the possibilities but non have worked yet, I wish to show the data from the database on the repeatbox. I am able to get the data but real problem occurs when I want to show the respective page on each item click.

below is the test code which I am using in callback function to show the retrieved test data on the repeatbox.

```
function Listalluser_callBack(ul) {

    var userdata = ul.split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < userdata.length - 1; i++) {
        var rowdata = userdata[i].split(",");
        var productsObj = {}
        productsObj.Id = rowdata[0];
        productsObj.Username = rowdata[1];
        productsObj.Password = rowdata[2];
        productsData.push(productsObj);

    }

    var lbl = new SMF.UI.Label({
            top : "0%",
            left : "0%",
            width : "10%",
            height : "100%",
            fillColor : "#FFFFFF",

            textAlignment : SMF.UI.TextAlignment.cente

        });

    var lbl1 = new SMF.UI.Label({
            top : "0%",
            left : "10%",
            width : "70%",
            height : "100%",
            fillColor : "#FFFFFF",
            textAlignment : SMF.UI.TextAlignment.center
        });

    var imgbtn = new SMF.UI.ImageButton({

            top : "0%",
            left : "80%",
            height : "100%",
            width : "20%"

        });

    var repeatBox1 = new SMF.UI.RepeatBox({
            width : "100%",
            height : "95%",
            left : "0%",
            top : "0%",
            showScrollbar : true,
            fillColor : "white",
            backgroundTransparent : true

        });

    imgbtn.defaultImage = "ic_action_next_item.png";
    //imgbtn.text = "";
    imgbtn.onTouch = function (e) {

       // alert(imgbtn.text);
       alert(repeatBox1.controls[2].text);

    }

    repeatBox1.dataSource = productsData;
    repeatBox1.onRowRender = function (e) {
        this.controls[0].text = productsData[e.rowIndex].Id;
        this.controls[1].text = productsData[e.rowIndex].Username;
        this.controls[2].text = productsData[e.rowIndex].Id;
    };

    repeatBox1.onSelectedItem = function (e) {
        alert("Selected " + (e.rowIndex + 1) + ". row");
    };

    repeatBox1.onRowDeleting = function (e) {
        if (e.rowIndex === 0) {
            alert("first row is deleted...");
        }
    };

    repeatBox1.autoSize = true;

    repeatBox1.itemTemplate.height = Device.screenHeight / 8;
    repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(lbl);
    repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(lbl1);
    repeatBox1.itemTemplate.add(imgbtn);

    repeatBox1.layoutType = SMF.UI.LayoutType.linear;
    repeatBox1.horizontalGap = 5;
    //repeatBox1.groupItems = true;
    repeatBox1.useActiveItem = true;

    Pages.pgHome.add(repeatBox1);

}
```

Any other sample code which can be used to show the respective page depending upon the condition for example as below depending on id i have to show his profile on the other page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its working now using following code 
imgbtn.onTouch = function (e) {

     alert(productsData[e.rowIndex - 1].Username);

    }

Answer (score 0):

To change a page according to a pressed row, you can use the onSelectedItem function.

```js
repeatboxReference.onSelectedItem = function(e){
  switch(e.rowIndex){
    case 0:
      Pages.Page1.show(/*params*/);
      break;
    case 1:
      Pages.Page2.show(/*params*/);
      break;
    //And so on
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks @luccas code is working and I needed the rowindex on image click which is now working fine. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score -1):

You should refresh your repeatbox and also use `repeatBox1.show();` to show the box